# Docker mounted volume javascript not syncing

Tags: javascript, docker, caching, mounted-volumes

I am using an nginx container, to which I mount a volume containing my application, and copy it into the html folder:

```
docker run --name myApp -P -d -v /path/to/myApp:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

i can now navigate to myApp in the browser, and edit both the index.html file, myApp.js, and the changes a reflected in the server, therefore in the browser.

After a little while though the changes to myApp.js are not synced anymore, only the modifications to the html file are.

any ideas what is going on here?

I have had the same issue with php and i had to disable the php cache, but javascript runs in the browser hence i don't know where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-do-we-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers) might answer your Browser caching issues.

> The correct minimum set of headers that works across all clients (and proxies):

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

You should also confirm that it is caching, by opening your website via CLI curl or browser's Incognito mode..